# Подскажите книги по java ee

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, книги

Желательно на русском

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все книги на русском, с направлением веб разработки:

> "Blinov Java Industr Programming"
>
> "Дэвид Гери, Кей Хорстманн -
>   JavaServer Faces. 3-е издание"
>
> "Ильдар
>   Хабибуллин - Разработка web-служб
>   средствами Java" - исключительно для
>   изучения веб служб, таких как WSDL

**UPD**

> Дэвид Хеффельфингер: Java EE 6 и
>   сервер приложений GlassFish

Comment: На первую ссылку не дадите? А то я ничего по ней нагуглить не смог

Comment: выложил на ex, ссылка в ответе

Comment: ???
![alt text][1]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/CblhWXR.png

Comment: бывает, если вы не с Украины :)
куда выложить ?

Comment: Если по быстрому, то narod.ru. А вообще для таких дел есть dropbox --> share this file

Comment: поправил первую ссылку, по идее должна работать и добавил вторую на us.ua(что первое гугл выдал, туда и залил)

Comment: Спс, работает :).
p.s. ну вы и патриот :)

Comment: дык первая ссылка в гугле :)

Answer (score 1):

На английском книг по J2EE раз 2 и обчелся, а вы на русском просите.
Рекомендую Beginning Java EE 6 with GlassFish 3. Читайте с переводчиком, переводите незнакомые слова, английский пригодится.

Comment: Ага, и пойму 1/3 книжки. У меня и так процент усваемости низкий, а если ещё и на иглише читать...

Comment: я также начинал. потом как-то само пошло. на английском языке техническая литература гораздо легче читается.

Comment: Если поймете только 1/3 книжки, то прочтите ее трижды) Если собираетесь работать в J2EE, то скорее всего заказчик будет иностранный. И без знания английского Вы не получите работу. А прочитав и разобравшись, убъете двух зайцев: J2EE выучите и язык подтяните

Comment: @Антон Феоктистов

1. Ну почему сразу заказчик? На себя я работать права не имею :)? Да и для общения с заказчиком сойдут куда более меньшие познания инглиша

2. Учу инглиш и года через 3-4 овладею. Мне ждать 3-4 года? Тоже пас

3. А если так:?

![alt text][1]

Причём с каждым новым заходом количество нового усваиваемого будет меньше, т.к. пойдёт усваивание усвоенного). Да и 2 раза книгу читать неохота, что уж там про 3+ 
  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/TJISRV3.png

Comment: @danpetruk

аххахаах) картинка отличная) имхо, со знаниями j2ee на себя работать трудно. А книжки на инглише все равно начинайте уже сейчас читать - Вы быстрее язык выучите.